# ADODB Connections and recordset in shared workbook

Tags: excel, adodb, vba

Can I using ADODB.Connections and ADODB.Recordset in shared woorkbook. I try to run a macro, but I have Run Time Error: External table is not in the expected format. Part of the code works. Code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub proc()

Dim CnExcel As ADODB.Connection
Dim RstExcel As ADODB.Recordset
Dim user As String

Application.EnableEvents = False

user = Environ("USERNAME") 'that's working

    Range("A2").Select 'that's working
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select 'that's working
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select 'that's working
    Selection.ClearContents 'that's working

Set CnExcel = New ADODB.Connection

With CnExcel
    .Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
    .Mode = adModeRead
    .CursorLocation = adUseClient
    .Properties("Data Source") = "C:\MB_Form.xlsm"
    .Properties("Extended Properties") = ("Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1")
    .Open
End With

Set RstExcel = New ADODB.Recordset
RstExcel.Open "SELECT * FROM [Arkusz1$]", CnExcel

Dim i As Integer
i = 2

Do Until RstExcel.EOF
    If Not IsNull(RstExcel.Fields("PESEL").Value) Then
        Cells(i, 1).Value = RstExcel.Fields("ID").Value
        Cells(i, 2).Value = RstExcel.Fields("Name").Value
        Cells(i, 3).Value = RstExcel.Fields("City").Value
        i = i + 1
    End If
    RstExcel.MoveNext
Loop

CnExcel.Close

End Sub
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using the ACE OLEDB driver and specifying Excel 12.0 Macro as the type:

```
With CnExcel
    .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
    .Mode = adModeRead
    .CursorLocation = adUseClient
    .Properties("Data Source") = "C:\MB_Form.xlsm"
    .Properties("Extended Properties") = "Excel 12.0 Macro;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"
    .Open
End With
```